# Whats the difference between these two C++ syntax for passing by reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm learning modern C++ and sometimes I see values passed by reference written slightly differently with a space.

```
int &i
```

Is there a difference?

```
int& x
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapnum(int &i, int &j) {
  int temp = i;
  i = j;
  j = temp;
}

void f(const int& x) {
  int& y = const_cast<int&>(x);
  ++y;
}
```

Comment: No, the spacing makes no difference at all.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the ampersand `&` position? No, there is no semantic difference.

Comment: Same as mentioned in the duplicate applies for the `&`.

Comment: The const, on the other hand, does make a difference. Wouldn't be surprised if your `f()` function causes undefined behavior the way it modifies a value obtained from a const reference.

Comment: If you're not asking about the difference with the `const` specifier, then please *remove it*. It's irrelevant to your question and confusing.

Comment: Also note that what your function `f` is doing is ***bad***. If the argument passed to `f` is indeed a constant (one way or another) then the function will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't cast away `const` unless you 100% know it's safe.

Comment: Funny you say that. It came from this link. I would agree too when I saw it but I just used it to ask my question. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr233.htm

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, there is no difference.  As far as I am concerned, the first drives me into a furious indignant rage, and the second makes me happy.

Answer (score 3):

No, the spacing makes no difference at all. What makes the difference in your example is the `const` keyword (which isn't the question here).

Spacing doesn't really matter, except your colleagues may complain about bad styling. These forms are equivalent to the compiler:

```
int &i;
int& i;
int&i;
int
&
i;
```

The compiler will parse the code into "lexical elements" before further processing, and space only serves as separators.